Fast reading from a TSV file in Rust
I have a TSV file that contains bunch of lines prefixed with #. While there are several columns in the file, I want only first and third columns - and those columns are duplicated, so I want to reduce it as much as I can.
The function in Python that does this:
def read_faulty_tsv(path):
    # 1.74 s ± 18.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
    with open(path) as _f:
        i = 0
        header = None
        for line in _f.readlines():
            if line.startswith("#"):
                i += 1
            else:
                break

    data = pd.read_csv(path, sep="\t", skiprows=i, header=None)
    data = data.drop_duplicates([0,2])
    return data

As noted with the timeit magic, the execution time is 1.74s which is great!
EDIT2: The python code takes columns 0 and 2, and then drops duplicates based on two columns. I hadn't specified, as it is not important and it does not impact the solution - but columns 0 and 2 are correlated. Think column 0 being a number X and column 2 being a number 2X. In fact, Python code is somewhat ill-optimized. I would modify it to be:
return data.drop_duplicates([0])
or just
return dict(zip(data[0],data[2])). Performance remains same-ish: 1.86 s ± 12.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each).
A similar function in Rust is slower. I've tried two options - one which just native methods, and another using csv crate (csv="1.1" in .toml). The first one takes 5.260 seconds and the second one takes 7.729 seconds which is drastically slower!
Am I doing something very wrong to have Python out-perform Rust?
The functions are below (EDIT2: Included use statements) :
use csv::ReaderBuilder;
use std::time::Instant;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::fs::File;
use std::error::Error;
use std::collections::{HashSet,HashMap};
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn read_fault_tsv(file_path:&PathBuf)->Result<HashMap<u32,u32>, Box<dyn Error>>{
    
    let mut final_labels: HashMap<u32, u32> = HashMap::new();
    
    let file = File::open(file_path)?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    // Create a vector to store non-comment lines
    let mut lines = Vec::new();

    let start_time = Instant::now();
    // Read lines and skip comment lines
    for line in reader.lines() {
        let line = line?;
        if !line.starts_with('#') {
            lines.push(line);
        }
    }
    let joined_lines = lines.join("\n");
    // Create a CSV reader with tab delimiter from the collected lines
    let mut rdr = ReaderBuilder::new()
        .delimiter(b'\t')
        .from_reader(joined_lines.as_bytes());
    for result in rdr.records(){
        match result {
            Ok(record)=>{
                let first_c = record[0].parse::<u32>().unwrap();
               if !final_labels.contains_key(&first_c){
                let third_c = record[0].parse::<u32>().unwrap();
                final_labels.insert(first_c,third_c);
                }
        }
            Err(e) => {
                eprintln!("Error -- {}",e)
            }
        }
    }
    let elapsed_time = start_time.elapsed();
    println!("Elapsed time: {}.{:03} seconds", elapsed_time.as_secs(), elapsed_time.subsec_millis());
    Ok(final_labels)
    
}

fn read_fault_tsv2(file_path:&PathBuf)->Result<HashMap<u32,u32>, Box<dyn Error>>{
    let mut final_labels: HashMap<u32, u32> = HashMap::new();

    let file = File::open(file_path)?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    let lines = reader.lines()
    .filter_map(Result::ok)
    .filter(|line|!line.starts_with('#'));
    let start_time = Instant::now();
    for line in lines{
        let columns: Vec<&str> = line.split('\t').collect();
        if columns.len() > 2 {
            if let Ok(key) = columns[0].parse::<u32>() {
                if !final_labels.contains_key(&key) {
                    if let Ok(value) = columns[2].parse::<u32>() {
                        final_labels.insert(key, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    };
    let elapsed_time = start_time.elapsed();
    println!("Elapsed time: {}.{:03} seconds", elapsed_time.as_secs(), elapsed_time.subsec_millis());
    
    Ok(final_labels)
}

EDIT1:
User kmdreko asked if I built with the --release. I must confess I did not. I then modified the launch.json to include that flag in the build arguments, so that I get the following :
cargo build --release --bin=telomeres --package=MYPACKAGE --message-format=json
The running times were now 2.486 seconds and 3.971 second which is roughly half the time, but still way slower than Python.

You might want to try with the polars crate: https://crates.io/crates/polars which is the pandas equivalent written in Rust.

Obligatory: Are you building with the --release profile?

@kmdreko See the EDIT. Even with --release it's way slower than Python.

your code doesn't do what python does you are comparing apple to orange. when you post code please include use statement it's not optional.

use real crate https://crates.io/crates/csv, https://docs.rs/csv/1.3.0/csv/struct.ReaderBuilder.html#method.comment

@Stargateur I've added use statements above, and clarified the difference between Python code and Rust code.  And as I've mentioned in the OP: using csv crate (csv="1.1" in .toml).  I've also tried 1.3. And Python is still faster.

well, I don't want to read all your code, ReaderBuilder::new().comment(Some(b'#')) ! and your code to remove duplicate is probably not good. Anyway you use pandas that is coded in C I think so it's not surprising the "python" implementation is pair with Rust... do a pure python impl of csv and compare :p

@Stargateur I should note that I'm not "removing duplicates" per-se, but more like extracting unique values - the difference between the two is cosmetic. I'm also curious to think why my code to remove duplicates is "probably not good" - I parse through the lines, check if the first element is in keys of a HashMap, and if it's not I add it with the third element. How can I improve on this? I kinda doubt that simply inserting without checking would improve performance on par with pandas. Likewise, Python, AFAIK, is primarily written in C so I don't know why you used quotation marks on "python".

please include example file. cause pure python code is 20 time slower that rust at least, while pandas is not python it's just C with a python front API so it's not python it's "python".

Your python code use pandas that is write in C or Cython so you are comparing mostly Rust with C. It's not surprising they are close. Your Rust code can be a lot improved. The way to time the code is bad you should use tool like criterion.
Here a pseudo code that should be way faster it's not perfect cause you didn't include an example file:
use std::{collections::HashMap, error::Error, fs::File, io::BufReader, path::Path};

use csv::ReaderBuilder; // csv = "1.3.0"
use serde::Deserialize; // serde = { version = "1", features = ["derive"] }

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Row {
    a: u32,
    c: u32,
}

pub fn foo(file_path: &Path) -> Result<HashMap<u32, u32>, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let reader = BufReader::new(File::open(file_path)?);
    let rdr = ReaderBuilder::new()
        .delimiter(b'\t')
        .comment(Some(b'#'))
        .from_reader(reader);
    let mut labels: HashMap<u32, u32> = HashMap::new();
    for record in rdr.into_deserialize() {
        let row: Row = record?;
        labels.entry(row.a).or_insert_with(|| row.c);
    }
    Ok(labels)
}

#sep is \t !!!
a,b,c 0,1,2 3,4,5

use std::{error::Error, path::Path};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>{
  foo(Path::new("data.csv"))?;

  Ok(())
}

